# Playing video in surfaceview

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview

My app plays a video inside a surfaceview. And I stop the mediaplayer from playing when onPause(). However, when I return from another activity, the surfaceview is all black and starts to show frames only if I start playing video again. I want to know if there is a method to preserve the last frame when it stops. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you need to preserve it?  Can you just play one frame and re-pause the video when your app resumes?

Comment: @fadden Yeah, this is another solution but how can I play one frame? I have tried calling pause() right after start() and failed. Thank you!

Comment: Does the `seek()` method trigger a frame draw? If so, you can get the position before pause and seek to this frame when you resume the activity.

Comment: @JASONGPETERSON It will not

Answer (score 0):

I used 2 SurfaceViews, first for playing videos and second surf for displaying pictures.
when I return from pause, if mediaplayer is not playing, I get current frame of video by this part of code:

```
try {
    mediaMDRetriever.setDataSource(mediaPath);
    picBitmap = mediaMDRetriever.getFrameAtTime();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

and draw it on the second surfview.

you can clear second SurfaceView if needed by the following code:

```
Canvas surfCanvas = surfHolder2.lockCanvas();
surfCanvas.drawColor( 0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR );
surfHolder2.unlockCanvasAndPost( surfCanvas );
```